# SCOPE_IDENTITY Exception

Tags: dapper-simplecrud

I have been evaluating the use of dapper and the simplecrud extension with sqlite. No matter what I try when doing a table insert things fail with an exception

> no such function SCOPE_IDENTITY

Table class

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Simplest piece of code to test

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection( "Data Source=E:\\Databases\\MyDatabase.db;Version=3" );
    conn.Open();

    var usr = new User { Name = "Dave", Age = 65 };
    var id = conn.Insert(usr);
    conn.Close();
}
```

As indicated earlier when I run the code the data is inserted into the table but the program terminates with the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` exception.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a **SQL Server** function (and therefore not available in SQLite, obviously) - no idea why does would be showing up in your case..... Is there anything with Dapper or the Dapper extension that defaults to SQL Server, and you have to change it to SQLite, maybe

Comment: Marc_s, thanks your your reply. Not that I am aware of and have been unable to see anything in sample code on github, thus leading to extreme frustration.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the Github page, it seems the current release has dropped support for SQLite:

> Database support
>
> There is an option to change database dialect. **Default is Microsoft SQL Server** but can be changed to PostgreSQL or MySQL. **We dropped SQLite support** with the .Net Core release.
>
> SimpleCRUD.SetDialect(SimpleCRUD.Dialect.PostgreSQL);
>
> SimpleCRUD.SetDialect(SimpleCRUD.Dialect.MySQL);

Depending on which version you have, you *might* be able to use a similar call to set the SQLite "dialect" (if it's still supported in your code base).

Comment: Marc_s, that would explain it. I had missed that comment in the release, but had been misguided by the fact that the test code on github still references sqlite as a provider. Thank you.

Comment: Marc_s, looks like we have some confusion here, looking through the history on github, sqlite support was removed as of version 2.0.0 but was re-added as of version 2.0.1 which is the current version on nuget and what I have been using. Maybe the re-adding is not quite right.

Comment: @hypothesys: ok, so the support is back in there - and are you calling `SimpleCRUD.SetDialect(Dialect.SQLite)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: @hypothesys: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

i was using  dapper fastCrud i face the same issue. so add this line of code in my constructor.

```
 OrmConfiguration.DefaultDialect = SqlDialect.SqLite;
```